# Can somebody interpret this C++ line of code?

Tags: c++

Sorry, I'm a C++ novice.  I was looking through some code and ran across this line of code:

```
   string cmd(*iter);
```

Obviously the variable "cmd" is being defined as a string, but the part that I don't understand is the bit inside the parenthesis:  (*iter)

I know the "*iter" is a pointer but what does it mean to have a variable declaration followed by parenthesis?

Sorry for such a dumb question.

Comment: depends on '*iter''s type it can either copy it, or make a copy of a c string (null terminated char sequence).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In "classic" C++ language you have two forms of initialization syntax:

copy-initialization

```
int i = 5;
```

and direct-initialization

```
int i(5);
```

They are not always exactly the same, but for basic intents and purposes they do the same thing. (C++11 further extended the variety, but I won't go into that here.) In my above examples they are actually exactly the same: variable `i` will be initialized with `5` in both cases.

So your

```
string cmd(*iter);
```

has the same effect as

```
string cmd = *iter;
```

i.e. it initializes string `cmd` with value of `*iter`, where `iter` is probably an iterator of some kind.

Assuming `string` is actually the `std::string` class from Standard Library, your `string cmd(*iter)` will invoke one of `std::string`s constructors. Which one - depends on the type of `*iter`.

Answer (score 3):

initialize string cmd via `*iter`.

**NOTE:**
iter does not necessarily have to be a pointer, it could also be an iterator.

You should check the iterator's `*` operator.

Answer (score 1):

It is calling the constructor of the string class which accepts this kind of parameter. The same class can have different constructors.

Answer (score 1):

It calls the constructor of `string` with the value pointed by `iter`. This line of code simply creates a new `string` instance called `cmd` and initializes to the value of the iterator.